# Angular *ngFor loop through an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, html-table, ngfor

I have an array which contains other arrays inside like that:

```
array = [
           ["element A", "element B"],
           ["YES", "NO"]
        ]
```

And I want to loop through this array of object in an HTML table using ngFor:

```
   <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>#</th>
         <th>COLUMN 1</th>
         <th>COLUMN 2</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody>
       <template *ngFor="let row of csvContent; let in = index">
         <th scope="row">{{in}}</th>
            <template *ngFor="let c of row; let in = index">
              <td>
               {{c[0]}}
              </td>
            </template>
       </template>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

I want to display each inner array list below COLUMN1 and COLUMN2 respectively:

```
 COLUMN1   | COLUMN2
 --------------------
 element A | YES
 element B | NO
```

I can't figure it out how to use *ngFor properly in order to list an array of arrays (Simple list of strings). At the moment, it's either an empty array or a shifted & messed up Table presentation.

This is how looks the Table:

[image: shifted HTML Table using *ngFor]

Or this wrong presentation because Element A and B should be below COLUMN 1 and YES, NO should be below COLUMN2:

[image]

Comment: your example doesnt have a valid array syntax

Comment: @Jota.Toledo The array is perfectly fine, I just tried to represent how the Table should look like. I add now a screenshot to make it clear.

Comment: no, remove the 1: and 2: from your example and that would be fine

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Thanks for your suggestion, I made the array looks correct now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your data is not arrays in arrays; it's two connected arrays. You need to treat it as such:

```
   <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let column of csvContent[0]; let in = index">
       <td>
         {{csvContent[0][in]}}
       </td>
       <td>
         {{csvContent[1][in]}}
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
```

This is not really a good way of organizing your data, as stuff is not really related. What if `csvContent[0]` gets a new entry, but 1 doesn't? Right now, your data doesn't represent a table, and I'd recommend transforming it in your controller to be tabluar, and then printing.

Comment: What do you mean by "stuff is not really related"? it's a simple Array which contains other arrays with several strings. I believe *ngFor has a way to show multi-dimensional array. Don't worry about organizing the data, it's coming from a static CSV file.

Comment: @NizarBsb, your array is not organized by rows, it's organized by columns.

Comment: That's right, does it means I need to rethink the structure of my array?

Comment: RhoVisions has the only correct answer here, surprised Adeeb even  got an upvote. I would've restructured the array, but RhoVisions answer is completely acceptable

Comment: You have data in one array that is related to a field in a different array; there's no actual tabular relationship there. Your data describes columns, indexed by row, which is the inverse of the data you need. So you do need to worry about the incoming data. Thus why I suggested you transform it. You're ripe for problems.

Comment: @lancovivi I also recommend restructuring, thus the last line of my answer. Inverting the structure relationship will cause the least headaches over time.

Comment: @RhoVisions I understand, HTML requires the rows to be next to each other. This is definitely a valid answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>#</th>
         <th>COLUMN 1</th>
         <th>COLUMN 2</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let row of csvContent;let i = index;">
          <td>{{i}}</td>
          <td *ngFor="let c of row">
              {{c}}
          </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

I wasn't sure how your data looked like, but seems like this would help.
You don't really need to use `<template>` tags (they're deprecated anyway in favor of `<ng-template>` tags.

Also, no need for index tracking if you're gonna access the array at that index anyway.

Comment: I've attached a screenshot, your snippet does not show the Table properly, I still have the same issue.

Comment: I updated now with the first column showing the index

Comment: I have added a second screenshot to show you the result of your snippet. As you can see, the presentation is there but the rows are not below the right column.

Comment: This is not going to work that way, think that element A and element B need to be below COLUMN1 and finally YES, NO need to be below COLUMN2. At the moment this is showing inline as the screenshot of a wrong example.

Comment: Please notice I added a first `<td>{{i}}</td>` to every `<tr>` in the loop.

Comment: This wasn't in my previous version of the answer, this is the thing that'll solve your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162745/discussion-between-nizar-bsb-and-amit).

Comment: Can anyone tell me in the same table if i have a delete button and i use splice to remove an element,so how at the end will i get the same structure of array with the respective element of that respective array removed.

Answer (score 3):

Simply loop like this

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>COLUMN 1</th>
      <th>COLUMN 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of csvContent;let i = index;">
      <td>{{i}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let c of row">{{c}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: My answer exactly