# Iterating through Object data returned asynchronously through Promise in Angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I receive an array of Question objects that looks something like this: [Picture of array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziC2e.png)
It consists of an array of question categories, with an array of questions within it. I initialize the object with `board: JeopardyBoard = new JeopardyBoard();`, then I populate it in the init of my component by running:

```
getGame(showNumber: number, round: string): Promise<JeopardyBoard> {
    var url = this.gamesUrl
    return this.http.get(url)
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => response as JeopardyBoard)
                .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

We call this function in the component to set the board variable by running:

```
this.gameService.getGame(this.showNumberField, this.roundField).then(boardV => {this.board = boardV; console.log(this.board)});
```

I now try to parse out this data in the html by running:

```
<div class="board" *ngIf="!currentQuestion">
    <ul class="categories">
      <li *ngFor="let category of board.categories"><span class="category-name" [innerHTML]="category.title"></span>
        <ul class="category">
          <li *ngFor="let question of category.clues" (click)="setCurrentQuestion(question)"><span class="question-value" [innerHTML]="question.value"></span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

but nothing iterates inside fo the ngFor loops. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150500/angular-ngfor-loop-through-an-array-of-arrays) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748612/angularjs-ng-repeat-array-of-arrays) but haven't gotten it to work

edit: [link to the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7w9mob)

Comment: @AdritaSharma uploaded a rough one, couldn't get it completely working

Answer (score 0):

The data has been retrieved from server. You just need to update UI now.

```
  constructor(
     private gameService: GameService,
     private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}
```

Inside `getBoard` method

```
this.gameService
  .getGame(this.showNumberField, this.roundField)
  .then(boardV => {
    this.board = boardV;
    // Update UI
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    console.log(this.board);
  });
```